# reshape tensor in an autoencoder model using fashion mnist

Tags: reshape, torch, autoencoder, epoch, mnist

my code works fine for epoch number1 but when the epoch changes it stops working because of different shaping.
could you please help me to solve this problem?
I really appreciate your time

```
transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])
        trainTransform  = torchvision.transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(), torchvision.transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))])
        trainset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root='{}/./data'.format(path_prefix), train = True, download = True, transform = transform)
        train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)
        valset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(root='{}/./data'.format(path_prefix), train=False, download=True, transform=transform)
        val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valset, batch_size=32, shuffle=False, num_workers=4)


def train(self, epoch):
        # Note that you need to modify both trainer and loss_function for the VAE model
        self.model.train()
        train_loss = 0
        for batch_idx, (data, _) in tqdm(enumerate(self.train_loader), total=len(self.train_loader) ) :
            data = data.view(data.shape[0], -1)

            data = data.to(self.device)
            #print(data.shape)
            #print(data)
            self.optimizer.zero_grad()
            recon_batch = self.model(data)
            loss = self.loss_function(recon_batch, data)
            loss.backward()
            train_loss += loss.item()
            self.optimizer.step()

        train_loss /= len(self.train_loader.dataset)/32 # 32 is the batch size
        print('====> Epoch: {} Average loss: {:.4f}'.format(
              epoch, train_loss ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try deleting "num_workers=4" statement in train and val loaders. I had the same kind of error and this was the cause. Also tqdm makes things complicated so if you still have the error try to edit your code without it.